# NUnit components for version 4.0.30319 of the CLR are not installed

Tags: nunit

I am trying to implement an automated build process. After the build, the unit tests on nunit-console.exe are run. The following error is displayed:

```
> c:\nunit_2.5.10\nunit-console.exe c:\builds\Output\bin\TDD.nunit /framework=4.0.30319 /nologo /trace=Off
ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Default
Execution Runtime: v4.0.30319
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: NUnit components for version 4.0.30319 of the CLR are not installed
Parameter name: targetRuntime
   at NUnit.Util.TestAgency.LaunchAgentProcess(RuntimeFramework targetRuntime, Boolean enableDebug)
   at NUnit.Util.TestAgency.CreateRemoteAgent(RuntimeFramework framework, Int32 waitTime, Boolean enableDebug)
   at NUnit.Util.TestAgency.GetAgent(RuntimeFramework framework, Int32 waitTime, Boolean enableDebug)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)
```

There is no nunit-agent.exe on the build machine. However, on my machine it is not even called, so I suppose it is not necessary.

Why is nunit-agent.exe required in some cases but not always required? What conditions should be satisfied so nunit-agent would not need to launch?

Edit: I have found one resource, which kind of describes how it works, but not quite well: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-agent&r=2.5.10. It says that it is launched when program needs to run under a different framework than the one being used by NUnit (which is the case, since NUnit is compiled for 2.0). However, on my machine the nunit-agent.exe does not run although conditions seem to be the same.

Comment: Any resolution for this?

Comment: No. As far as I remember, I moved the build and unit testing processes to the local build machine and sent the artifacts to the "real" build machine. Nobody really bothered to check what might be wrong with it and I did not have access permissions.

Comment: @Glenn old post but I answered it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into this same error and it was definitely solved by including `nunit-agent.exe` in the folder where `nunit-console.exe` was launched. The complete list of `.exe`s and `.dll`s necessary to run a test successfully was:

```
nunit.core.dll
nunit.core.interfaces.dll
nunit.framework.dll
nunit.util.dll
nunit-agent.exe
nunit-console.exe
nunit-console-runner.dll
```

All files are packaged in the download available from [nunit.org](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download). As of this post, 2.6.3 is the current version. Documentation for the console runner can be found [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.6.3). And the direct download for the zip file is [here](http://launchpad.net/nunitv2/trunk/2.6.3/+download/NUnit-2.6.3.zip).

For a test assembly targeting .NET 4.5.1, the following statement will execute tests:

```
nunit-console.exe your-assembly.dll /framework=v4.5.1
```

Comment: Just ran into this, and adding nunit-agent.exe solved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Adding a "startup/supportedRuntime" configuration tag to `nunit-console.exe.config` solved it for me.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fusion to see what assembly might be missing and where the .exe is looking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx